# toLocaleDateString is giving different results

Tags: javascript, date, date-formatting

I am using below function. It is giving the output as **Jul-7,-1988** for few users. It is working fine for all the users and giving correct result like  7-Jul-1988. Anyone knows how to fix this issue. I want the result to be in 07-Jul-1988 format for all the users. And why does it is changing into different format when I have specifically mention the format 'en-GB'.

```
function(data) {
    var date = new Date(data);  
   
    return date.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', {
        day: 'numeric', month: 'short', year: 'numeric'
      }).replace(/ /g, '-')
}
```

I have found on this link - https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/33761 that it behave differently. In my case also it could be the same issue ?

Update: Can I use the below approach to get the date in desired format or moment.js would be better idea?

```
    function(data){
    var months = ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR","APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"];
   var current_datetime = new Date(data);
    var formatted_date = current_datetime.getDate() + "-" + months[current_datetime.getMonth()] + "-" + current_datetime.getFullYear()
   console.log(formatted_date)
   }
```

Comment: Users have control over how exactly they want localized dates to display. Even if my system is set to `en-GB` locale, I can still _specify_ what exactly I want that to look like, and/or what order I want the date components to display in.

Comment: locale is not definied by standards (the names yes, and the format, but not the content). Every OS and language could choose different locale definitions.

Comment: @CBroe so what can I try to fix the issue ?

Comment: The output of `toLocaleDateString` is meant to be a human-readable string with as much of what you specify applied as makes sense in the given format/locale. It's **definitely not** a fixed format that you should expect and try to tweak further. If you want a fixed format, don't use methods meant for locale-specific formatting.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Can I use this   function(data){
    var months = ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR","APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"];
   var current_datetime = new Date(data);
    var formatted_date = current_datetime.getDate() + "-" + months[current_datetime.getMonth()] + "-" + current_datetime.getFullYear()
   console.log(formatted_date)
   }

Comment: @CBroe—re "*Users have control over how exactly they want localized dates to display*" No they don't, the format is entirely up to the host developers. The rest of what you say is correct though: ECMA-262 suggests using the [*CLDR*](http://cldr.unicode.org), but it's not required and even then there are variations.